# Missing Font on Page in Firefox, Worked before and Still Works Now in Other Browsers

Tags: firefox, fonts

On [any new Steam profile](http://steamcommunity.com/id/keavon/), there are many parts of the page (such as the username) that is supposed to be following this font hierarchy:

'Motiva Sans Thin',Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,sans-serif

However, Motiva Sans Thin is not showing in Firefox anymore. It used to several days earlier, but now it reverts to Arial. Chrome, the Steam client, and other browsers still display Motiva Sans Thin, which leads me to believe it's still in my system's fonts, or still being provided as a web font.

I have tried creating a new Firefox profile to no avail. It's been doing this for about two weeks now. I am using Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Why is Firefox no longer displaying the font when it used to, and other browsers still do? How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Noto Font family will help.

most Linux systems have a fonts-noto package.

Under other OS's just install the noto symbols fonts :

1. Noto Sans Symbols https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Symbols
2. Noto Sans Symbols 2 https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Symbols+2

of course other fonts with the required symbols will also work, Noto is free and has most Glyphs (Characters)